# Get mouse click position cordinates

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to know the click position in the javascript page?
So, if you know the x,y position and want to the user to click that, return x,y?
and making some maths,
if the object in my page is a circle, can I add the polar ecuation coordinates of the circle in the (x,y)?

already tryed this when the image is clicked

```
 var container = document.getElementById("portada");
container.addEventListener("onClick", getClickPosition, false);

function getClickPosition(e){
var xpos = e.clientX;
var ypos = e.clientY;
console.log("x"+xpos);
console.log("y"+ypos);
}
```

But it gives me the undefined x and y, just tryed a similiar one and still undefined, any suggest?

Comment: You should show some code you tried, or examples you are trying to follow. The question is being downvoted because it appears you didn't researched and tried yourself before asking. It mat not be the case though.

Comment: @ItaloAyres added js function

Comment: `onClick` should be `click` as in `container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);`

Answer (score 1):

This could help. https://jsfiddle.net/oqmvutfc/

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    alert('x:'+e.pageX+' y:'+e.pageY);
});
```

`e.pageX` returns the X position and `e.pageY` returns the Y position.

Comment: im testing the app on devices, cant do alert, it's more simply to do on html txt